# How to create a set of dictionary keys from an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictonary like so:

```
{
    "x": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    "y": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "d": 4
    }
}
```

The values of each key are a dictionary. I want to create a `set` of all the keys of these dictionaries so like in the example above:

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
```

I have spent a long time on this but always end up with the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'`.

My code at the moment is:

```
set(item.keys() for item in [dictonary for dictonary in self.data.values()])
```

Ideally, I don't want to use any modules but if needs must I will.

Comment: "x" and "y" are keys too, why aren't they included?

Comment: They aren't the key's I want, it's quite a specific case but they shouldn't be in there.

Comment: Then you should clarify in your post, because you say you want "all the keys".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make one of two *tiny* changes to make what you've written work:

1. Union the `keys` objects (and remove the pointless no-op inner listcomp):

   ```
   set().union(*[dictionary.keys() for dictionary in self.data.values()])
   # Or somewhat less obviously, but more efficiently, you can just union 
   # the dicts themselves, which already act as collections of their keys:
   set().union(*self.data.values())
   ```

   This makes an empty set, then unpacks all the keys views (or the `dict`s themselves) as positional arguments to union with it; `set.union` takes varargs, so you can pass it any number of collections to union together at once.
2. Correctly use nested loops in a *single* comprehension, not a comprehension nested inside another (that doesn't unpack the way you were likely expecting):

   ```
   set(item for dictionary in self.data.values() for item in dictionary)
   # Or slightly better, but not as close to what you wrote, a true set comprehension
   {item for dictionary in self.data.values() for item in dictionary}
   ```

   Note the order of the looped things is different; the left-most loop in such a multiloop comprehension is the outer loop, moving to inner loops as you go to the right.

Comment: @wim: Yeah, I was editing to add that at the moment you commented (I was initially erring on "closest to what OP wrote", then adding "better/more idiomatic" solutions). Would have beat you to it, but I decided to type out a better explanation of what was going on. :-)

Comment: That's what I was looking for! The second one is better as for my use case I suspect people won't understand the * command to unpack an array. Could you explain the code a little more please, I can't work out how it "knows" to only use the keys?

Comment: @GAP2002: In most use cases where you use a `dict` as if it were a normal collection, not a mapping, it behaves as a collection of its keys alone. The `.keys()` method is therefore pointless *unless* you're specifically using the `set`-like behaviors it provides (support for `|`, `&`, `-`, `^`, `<`, `>`, etc.). Otherwise, if all you're doing is just looping over the `.keys()` (or membership testing with `in`), you'd get the exact same result performing the operation on the `dict` itself, without the small overhead of making the keys view object.

Comment: In short, in Python 3 (the rules in Py2 were different) all uses of `in dict.keys()` can be `in dict` (whether it's a looping construct or a membership test) and it's shorter/simpler and equivalent. And any time a function expects an iterable, with no special behavior for mappings, passing the `dict` itself is equivalent to passing a view of the same `dict`'s keys.

Answer (score 4):

Your immediate problem is that you tried to add the list of keys to your set.
This *would* have resulted in the set `{['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']}`, except that you cannot put a mutable element into a set (unhashable).

Instead, you need to iterate through those keys and get them into the set individually.

Also note that `[dictionary for dictionary in self.data.values()]` is better expressed as `list(self.data.values())`.

```
src = {
    "x": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    "y": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "d": 4
    }
}

result = set(key for item in src.values() for key in item.keys())
print(result)
```